# NIFI secure 3 node cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

I am seeing some errors in my nifi cluster, I have a 3 node secured nifi cluster i am seeing the below errors. at the 2 nodes

```
ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Unable to load flow due to: 
java.io.IOException: org.apache.nifi.cluster.ConnectionException: 
Failed to connect node to cluster due to: java.io.IOException: 
Could not begin listening for incoming connections in order to load balance data across the cluster. 
Please verify the values of the 'nifi.cluster.load.balance.port' and 'nifi.cluster.load.balance.host' 
properties as well as the 'nifi.security.*' properties
```

Comment: Could you please add more detail?
The error said to check some property, could you share these properties?

Comment: I have exact same issue while running the cluster through docker. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the [clustering configuration guide](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#clustering) for the list of clustering options you have to configure. For load balancing, you'll need to specify ports that are open in your firewall so that the nodes can communicate. You'll also need to make sure that each host has its node hostname property set, its host ports set and that there are no firewall restricts between the nodes and your Apache Zookeeper cluster.

If you want to simplify the setup to play around, you can use the information in the clustering configuration section of the admin guide to set up an embedded ZooKeeper node within each NiFi instance. However, I would recommend setting up an external ZooKeeper cluster. A little more work, but ultimately worth it.